# keeping the server name and IP address updated in the SAN

Tags: emc

In the Navisphere's attached server report, the HBA UIDs are displayed along with the host names and IP addresses of the Linux and windows servers that were previously registered. The Servers now have new names and new IP addresses but I continue to see the old ones. How do I make sure the new Host name and IP is updated on SAN? Will installing the naviagent on the servers resolve this problem? This was installed by people who are no longer working for us so there is no way to verify how it was done - my gut feeling is that it was registered manually. Appreciate your help here to ensure the updates or changes are automatically reflected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should be a feature of the Navisphere software.

Here's a related question with some good info: [Changing IP address of a host in Navisphere 6 (EMC array)](https://serverfault.com/questions/74708/changing-ip-address-of-a-host-in-navisphere-6-emc-array)